# Sketchup API on Mac

Tags: macos, api, dylib, sketchup

I am not able to have my CLI tool linked to slapi.framework working. It can be built, linked to the framework. I have added a Run Script build phase to copy the framework near the executable, and to change the @rpath of the executable:

```
set -x
DEST="$TARGET_BUILD_DIR"
mkdir -p "$DEST/Frameworks"
ln -fs "MY_PLACE/sdk/google-sketchup/macosx/slapi.framework" "$DEST/Frameworks"
install_name_tool -change @rpath/slapi.framework/Versions/Current/slapi @executable_path/Frameworks/slapi.framework/Versions/Current/slapi "$DEST/$TARGET_NAME"
```

When I run the executable, I got:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test_slapi
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libCommonUnits.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gdw/Documents/dev/code/test_slapi/Debug/./Frameworks/slapi.framework/Versions/Current/slapi
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the install name of slapi as you are doing. Instead, you should add slapi.framework's Libraries directory to your program's "Runpath Search paths".

But there is also a problem with the packaging of the framework. Please try the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd slapi.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
install_name_tool -id @rpath/libCommonUnits.dylib libCommonUnits.dylib
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Frameworks/libCommonUtils.dylib @rpath/libCommonUtils.dylib libCommonUnits.dylib
install_name_tool -change @executable_path/../Frameworks/libCommonGeometry.dylib @rpath/libCommonGeometry.dylib libCommonUnits.dylib
```

That should fix the install name for libCommonUnits.dylib.

Comment: You really shouldn't have to modify the install names within slapi. It uses rpath for that reason but in this case, one of the dylibs did not have proper install name. The code above is intended to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help... So it is common to change slapi rpath...

### I have made a shell to change every thing...

## ! /bin/sh

for d in ./Versions/Current/slapi ./Versions/Current/Libraries/*.dylib; do
    for p in $(otool -L "$d" | grep "@executable_path/../Frameworks/" | cut -f1 -d'('); do
    echo "$p"
    install_name_tool -id @rpath/$(basename "$p") "$p"
    install_name_tool -change "$p" @rpath/$(basename "$p") "$d"
    done

### done

Now, when I run the tool, I do no longer have link error, but an Illegal instruction: 4

The call stack shows:
_xpc_runtime_init_once (Thread 1: EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*,in, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long *)

Comment: Hmm. I have no idea what's causing that. Is your program 64-bit? Currently, slapi.framework is 32-bit only.

Comment: The error message displayed on the command line is "Illegal instruction: 4" but in the logs there is "XPC domain creation failed: Process is not in an inherited sandbox."... Sounds better, the solution is now very near!

Comment: ok, this is because this CLI tool is going to run as a child process of a signed and sandboxed application; for that it as an entitlements file where com.apple.security.inherit is set to YES. And so, this tool cannot bu run on a terminal directly...